# When click add button insert into table @name no name for Example "rose"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

```
try
{
    SqlConnection con;
    con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SEPEHR;Integrated Security=True;server=(local);Database=TEST");
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd;
    cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_custom (name , codemeli ,Adress) VALUES ('@name' , '@codemeli' , '@Adress')", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",t[enter image description here][1]xtname.Text.Trim());                
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codemeli",txtcodemeli.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adress",txtAdress.Text.Trim());

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    errorLabel.Text = ex.Message;
    errorLabel.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you expect to get and what you actually get.

Comment: I think you should remove the single quotes `'` around the parameters in your `Insert` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of those unneeded single quotes around the parameters in your `INSERT` statement:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_custom (name, codemeli, Adress) " + 
                     "VALUES (@name, @codemeli, @Adress)", con);
```